# Looking for real penetration testing reports

Tags: penetration-test

I'm wondering if there's any repository with leaked penetration testing reports? 
I found some samples but I'm not confident they are taken from real life cases.
Does any one know where can I find some?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic.

Comment: It is also easy to Google. The link in the answer below was #4 on the Google results.

Comment: @schroeder try to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaked? You mean, like, *published*?

https://github.com/juliocesarfort/public-pentesting-reports/ contains a "list of public penetration test reports released by several consulting firms and academic security groups".

I can confirm they are "real life cases" because it includes one of my employer.

Comment: No I was right when I wrote Leaked

Comment: @heismadatmelol When you say "leaked", you mean "illegally obtained, highly confidential data", and you wonder why people don't want to hand it to you.

Comment: @MechMK1
yeah i'm looking for those reports which were not publicly disclosed by anyone

Comment: Nit-pickers corner. The cardinality of the set of pen-test reports both 'publically available' and 'not publically disclosed' is small.

Comment: @heismadatmelol We are not sharing illegal content here.

Comment: @Luc I am aware of the "be nice" policy, but I feel at a disadvantage if I have to be nice, yet tons of new users don't bother at all learning the rules